# Pass a member function like a std::function in C++ (like in C#)

Tags: c#, c++, function, delegates, std-function

I have a template class Delegate, with an overloaded += operator, that makes using delegates similar to C#.

```
// ... generalized version of the template omitted from code
template<typename... TArgs>
    class Delegate<void, TArgs...>
    {
        private:
            using Func = std::function<void(TArgs...)>;
            std::vector<Func> funcs;

        public:
            template<typename T> Delegate& operator+=(T mFunc) { funcs.push_back(Func(mFunc)); return *this; }
            void operator()(TArgs... mParams) { for (auto& f : funcs) f(mParams...); }
    };
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
struct s
{
    void test() { }
    void run()
    {
        Delegate<void> d;
        d += [] { /* do something */ ; };
        d += test; // does not compile
    }
};
```

Is there a way to allow `d += test;` to work?

Comment: Doesn't it refuse to compile because `test` should not return smth, as it declared returning `void`? http://ideone.com/3sfQGU

Comment: @Lol4t0: agree, i just tried to compile it an had an empty `test`... that worked

Comment: Yeah I messed up - I wrote test right here in the stackOverflow editor. Editing.

Comment: Yes, you could provide an easy-to-compile example that shows what you're doing. As pointed out, it doesn't compile because of the `return` in `test` and capitalizing `Delegate` differently won't compile either.

Comment: Sorry it was just an example. I see that it works though, if I remove the return statement. I remember trying the same thing and it didn't compile - I think it was because I was trying to pass a member function, not a global one

Comment: I updated my post with real code I've tried compiling.

Comment: The `void s::test()` member function takes an implicit first parameter of type `s*`. You need `Delegate<void, s*>` or use `std::bind`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Delegate<void, s*> doesn't work. I don't want to use std::bind, as my goal is having the syntax d += test;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void test(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
```

How can it compile? This function is supposed to return nothing. Its return type is `void`.

Also, I assume you have defined (or declared ) the primary template:

```
template<typename R, typename... TArgs>
class Delegate;
```

Also assuming that `delegate` is a typo, as the class template is `Delegate`.

Anyway, with `test` returning nothing, it compiles fine:

http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c56b7a2e758f8fbc361228834c90822b

---

As for member-function-pointers, your current implementation doesn't support it. Note that a *non-static* member function pointer takes the form of `R (C::*MemPtr)(Args...) cv`. Just work on it.

Comment: I messed up writing test in the stackOverflow editor. I see that it compiles without the wrong result, though. I tried it earlier and it didn't work - I think I was using a member function though

Comment: @Vee: I've also updated my answer. Your implementation doesn't support member-function-pointer. You need to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions need an instance of an object to work on as well. You can give it as first parameter if you extract the function using `std::mem_fn` and you can also bind the current object to the function with `std::bind`

The code makes it clear:

```
struct s
{
    void test() { }
    void run()
    {
        Delegate<void> d;
        d += [] { /* do something */ ; };
        d += std::bind(std::mem_fn(&s::test), this); // does compile
    }
};
```

I don't really see a way for `d += test`. You really need to pass the actual object. This lambda version shows it even more clearly that you need the current object:

```
struct s
{
    void test() { }
    void run()
    {
        Delegate<void> d;
        d += [this] { test(); };
    }
};
```

Of course, you don't need to assign this in the operator+= line. You can modify the `Delegate` to take `this` in constructor like below (`runv1`), or add a member function that gives a proxy object that can add the test function (`runv2`): (I did not test these though)

```
struct s
{
    void test() { }
    void runv1()
    {
        Delegatev2<s, void> d(this);
        d += test;
    }
    void runv2()
    {
        Delegate<void> d;
        auto memd = d.getMemberDelegate(this);
        memd += test;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a little more clear. Is there any way to make it work with " d += test; " syntax?

Comment: What is the argument type for the runv1() delegate += operator override?

Answer (score 0):

As Nawaz said in edit, you use a member (non satic) function, it isn't compatible with void () signature of your std::function.

Two solution :

- Use something like `std::function<void(s&)>`
- bind your member function to an object, `std::bind(&s::test,&s);` (like K-ballo said, and Csq did)

Moreover, you should use rref and std::forward to achieve perfect forwarding.